# Unspecified height of div

Tags: html, css

[My page here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/events/2012/December/vintage-vogue-fashion-and-lifestyle-fair.html) on the left hand nav is showing the categories (`div.cat`) spaced out at `48px` height and I can't work out why.

There's no `padding` or `margin`s or `height` specified. If someone could have a look on an inspector to see what could be causing it that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clearfix is causing issues within the child.  The whole structure is a tangle of block and inline elements that should be cleaned up in one way or another.  Any block elements within each category seem unnecessary.  You probably also want to use a `ul` for greater semantic meaning.

Comment: and also, adding the same class to every child in a container is needless duplication.  `.quickjump > div`

Comment: the clearfix within each category link?  Right now you have a very convoluted design in the navbar, "fixing" it would just be burying the problem.  It seems like you're looking for a vertical list of images and text, so that's what the markup should express.  Each list item can be a block element and the contents can be inline, far less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

There is class `.cat` declared in the css file.

```
.cat, .cat a {
padding: 0 5px;
color: #444066;
}
```

remove the `padding` from there or reduce the padding from `5px` to `0px`

and another thing is found is in the `body` class

```
body {
line-height: 1.6;
font-size: 15px;
}
```

which increses `line-height` of all `div`s and elements

Comment: css plays very strange some time :)

Comment: the padding would be causing issues most likely due to the clearfix within the `a`.  The padding would also be applied around that which would force a new line.